# Python Urllib2 module Error

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2

Can somebody tell me what:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

exactly means? Could not find it in the documentation.

Does it say that the URL is incorrect?!

Comment: What are you trying to do? What in your code produces this error?

Answer (score 1):

I believe (-3) means EAI_AGAIN which in turn means DNS lookup timeout.

Here'a a list of the error codes and what they mean more or less

http://books.google.pl/books?id=kQom0WiUbZQC&pg=PA387&lpg=PA387&source=bl&ots=mrAyW5B_ck&sig=zN-mvD7RyccD6exeVMDwDftbldM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6ACzUZhXo6zgBP2sgLAH&sqi=2&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Might be a DNS issue - check your name resolver setup and carefully look at the URL you're trying to fetch.